# cloud foundry uploading java.war error

Tags: cloud-foundry

Time of crash:
  2013-01-26 17:14:45 +0800

Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument - C:/DOCUME~1/lihengxu/LOCALS~1/Temp/.vmc_aaaa_files/E:

C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `mkdir'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in`fu_mkdir'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:221:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in`reverse_each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `block in mkdir_p'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in`each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `mkdir_p'
cfoundry-0.4.19/lib/cfoundry/zip.rb:27:in`block in unpack'
rubyzip-0.9.9/lib/zip/zip_entry_set.rb:35:in `each'
rubyzip-0.9.9/lib/zip/zip_entry_set.rb:35:in`each'
rubyzip-0.9.9/lib/zip/zip_central_directory.rb:109:in `each'
rubyzip-0.9.9/lib/zip/zip_file.rb:132:in`block in foreach'
rubyzip-0.9.9/lib/zip/zip_file.rb:90:in `open'
rubyzip-0.9.9/lib/zip/zip_file.rb:131:in`foreach'
cfoundry-0.4.19/lib/cfoundry/zip.rb:24:in `unpack'
cfoundry-0.4.19/lib/cfoundry/upload_helpers.rb:58:in`prepare_package'
cfoundry-0.4.19/lib/cfoundry/upload_helpers.rb:42:in `upload'
vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli/app/push.rb:119:in`block in upload_app'
interact-0.5.1/lib/interact/progress.rb:98:in `with_progress'
vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli/app/push.rb:118:in`upload_app'
vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli/app/push.rb:100:in `setup_new_app'
vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli/app/push.rb:82:in`push'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/base.rb:61:in `run'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:68:in`block in invoke'
manifests-vmc-plugin-0.4.19/lib/manifests-vmc-plugin/plugin.rb:113:in `call'
manifests-vmc-plugin-0.4.19/lib/manifests-vmc-plugin/plugin.rb:113:in`block (2 levels) in '
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/callbacks.rb:74:in `with_filters'
manifests-vmc-plugin-0.4.19/lib/manifests-vmc-plugin/plugin.rb:112:in`block in '
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:78:in `instance_exec'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:78:in`block (2 levels) in invoke'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:82:in `instance_exec'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:82:in`invoke'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/base.rb:50:in `execute'
vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli.rb:106:in`execute'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership.rb:45:in `start'
vmc-0.4.7/bin/vmc:11:in`'
C:/Ruby193/bin/vmc:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby193/bin/vmc:23:in`'

how can i do?

Comment: which command did you try when it threw this stack trace?

Comment: Actually I mean can you be more specific on the issue? Did you try clean up the workspace or reinstall vmc? Did you successfully target vmc to api.cloudfoundry.com and logged in? If possible do you want to have a copy of your app for me to try deploying?

Comment: very thank u.the issue you said I had tried again and again.I'm sure that it doesn't matter with app . I will give you my app.thanks again.

Comment: I think the best way to get a private and responsive assistant agent is to file a ticket on CF support page: http://support.cloudfoundry.com. You can either attach your app in the ticket or share the location of your project on GitHub or any other source sharing hosts. I will be available there, my friend :)

Comment: Henry, did you get your issue resolved? If so would you mind re-posting the solution here for community awareness?